# Characters as numbers, comparing them

Tags: c, char

I've recently started programming and currently i'm working on a game.

In this game i need to compare current input with the last input from an array.
It's really easy in number systems up to decimal.

Here is the code that i've written and works with numbers from systems up to decimal.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define Max_size 256
#define N 36

void Game(int NumberSystem,int MaxRepetitions,char *Player1,char *Player2);

int main (void)
{

    int temp,status,NumberSystem,MaxRepetitions  ;

    char Player1 [Max_size] ;
    char Player2 [Max_size] ;
    printf("Please enter the first player's name\n");
    scanf("%s",&Player1);

    printf("Please enter the second player's name\n");
    scanf("%s",&Player2);


    printf("Please enter a Number System between %d and %d\n",4,35);
    status =  scanf("%d",&NumberSystem );

    while( NumberSystem  > 35 ||  NumberSystem < 4 || status != 1  )
    {
        while((temp=getchar()) != EOF && temp != '\n');
        printf("Please enter a valid Number System \n");
        status = scanf("%d", &NumberSystem );
    }




    printf("Please enter a Number of maximum repetitions\n");
    status = scanf("%d",&MaxRepetitions);

    while(  (MaxRepetitions<= 0) ||  (status != 1)   )
    {
        while((temp=getchar()) != EOF && temp != '\n');
        printf("Please enter a valid number of maximum repetitions\n");
        status = scanf("%d",&MaxRepetitions);
    }


    Game(NumberSystem,MaxRepetitions,Player1,Player2);


}


void Game(int NumberSystem,int MaxRepetitions,char *Player1,char *Player2)
{




    int status,counter,k,i,temp;
    char fnumber,number;

    counter = k = 1;

    int *array1 = malloc(MaxRepetitions*NumberSystem*sizeof(int));
    int *array2 = malloc(NumberSystem*sizeof(int));
    char CharArray[N] = {'0','1','2','3', '4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};

    for(i=0; i<NumberSystem*sizeof(int),i++;)
        array2[i] = 0;





    printf("Let's start the game! %s begins.\n",Player1);
    status = scanf("%d",&fnumber);

    while(status != 1  || fnumber <= 0 || fnumber>NumberSystem-1)
    {
        while((temp=getchar()) != EOF && temp != '\n');
        printf("First number must be a positive decimal number between %d and %d\n",1,NumberSystem-1);
        status = scanf("%d", &fnumber);
    }

    array1[0] = fnumber;
    array2[fnumber]++;


    while( array2[number] < MaxRepetitions)
    {
        status = scanf("%d",&number);

        while(status != 1  || number < 0 || number>NumberSystem-1 || ( (array1[k-1]!= NumberSystem-1) && (array1[k-1] >= number) )              )
        {
            while((temp=getchar()) != EOF && temp != '\n');
            printf("You must enter a number greater than %d and smaller or equal to %d\n",array1[k-1],NumberSystem-1);
            status = scanf("%d", &number);
        }

        array2[number]++;
        array1[k] = number;
        k++;
        counter++;

    }



    if(counter%2 == 0)
    {
        printf("%s entered %d for the %dth time and exceeded the possible limit. %s won!",Player2,array1[k-1],MaxRepetitions,Player1);
    }

    else
    {
        printf("%s entered %d for the %dth time and exceeded the possible limit. %s won!",Player1,array1[k-1],MaxRepetitions,Player2);
    }




    free (array1);
    free (array2);

}
```

Problem is i'd like it to be possible to play with greater numeric systems for example hexadecimal. I'm stuck at comparing value of the currently entered letter with letter that was entered before.

I'm seeking for any advice or suggestions.
Also if i did something really dumb in the first code (which probably i did) i would be glad to hear constructive criticism from you guys.

Thank you!

Here is the code to the "2nd" version where i tried to make this work with greater numeric systems. It's buggy and i don't know what have i done wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define Max_size 256
#define N 36

void Game(int NumberSystem,int MaxRepetitions,char *Player1,char *Player2);

int main (void)
{

    int temp,status,NumberSystem,MaxRepetitions  ;

    char Player1 [Max_size] ;
    char Player2 [Max_size] ;
    printf("Please enter the first player's name\n");
    scanf("%s",&Player1);

    printf("Please enter the second player's name\n");
    scanf("%s",&Player2);


    printf("Please enter a Number System between %d and %d\n",4,35);
    status =  scanf("%d",&NumberSystem );

    while( NumberSystem  > 35 ||  NumberSystem < 4 || status != 1  )
    {
        while((temp=getchar()) != EOF && temp != '\n');
        printf("Please enter a valid Number System \n");
        status = scanf("%d", &NumberSystem );
    }




    printf("Please enter a Number of maximum repetitions\n");
    status = scanf("%d",&MaxRepetitions);

    while(  (MaxRepetitions<= 0) ||  (status != 1)   )
    {
        while((temp=getchar()) != EOF && temp != '\n');
        printf("Please enter a valid number of maximum repetitions\n");
        status = scanf("%d",&MaxRepetitions);
    }


    Game(NumberSystem,MaxRepetitions,Player1,Player2);


}


void Game(int NumberSystem,int MaxRepetitions,char *Player1,char *Player2)
{

    int status,counter,k,i,temp;
    char fnumber,number;

    counter = k = 1;

    char *array1 = malloc(MaxRepetitions*NumberSystem*sizeof(char));
    int *array2 = malloc(NumberSystem*sizeof(int));
    char CharArray[N] = {'0','1','2','3', '4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};

    for(i=0; i<NumberSystem*sizeof(int),i++;)
        array2[i] = 0;

    printf("Let's start the game! %s begins.\n",Player1);


    //scanf("%c",&fnumber); // This part is ignored completely i don't know why

    status = 0;


   // for(i=0; i<NumberSystem-1; i++)
    //{if(fnumber == CharArray[i]) status = 1;}

    printf("Current status : %d\n",status);

    while(status == 0)
    {
        while((temp=getchar()) != EOF && temp != '\n');
        scanf("%c", &fnumber);



        for(i=0; i<NumberSystem-1; i++)
            if(fnumber == CharArray[i]) status = 1;break;

printf("First number must be a positive decimal number between %d and %d (in %d number system)\n",1,NumberSystem-1,NumberSystem);
    }

    array1[0] = fnumber;
    array2[fnumber]++;

    printf("Przed druga petla array1[0] : %c,array2[fnumber] : %d\n",array1[0],array2[fnumber]);


    while( array2[k] < MaxRepetitions)
    {
        scanf("%c",&number);
        status = 0;

        for(i=0; i<NumberSystem-1; i++)
            if(number == CharArray[i]) status = 1;

        while(status == 0   || ( (array1[k-1] != CharArray[NumberSystem-1]) && (array1[k-1] >= number) )              )
        {
            while((temp=getchar()) != EOF && temp != '\n');

            printf("You must enter a number greater than %c and smaller or equal to %d\n",array1[k-1],NumberSystem-1);
            scanf("%c", &number);

            status = 0;
            for(i=0; i<NumberSystem-1; i++)
                if(number == CharArray[i]) status = 1;break;

        }

        array2[number]++;
        array1[k] = number;
        k++;
        counter++;

    }

    if(counter%2 == 0)
    {
        printf("%s entered %d for the %dth time and exceeded the possible limit. %s won!",Player2,array1[k-1],MaxRepetitions,Player1);
    }

    else
    {
        printf("%s entered %d for the %dth time and exceeded the possible limit. %s won!",Player1,array1[k-1],MaxRepetitions,Player2);
    }

    free (array1);
    free (array2);

}
```

Comment: Too much code, narrow your problem down to [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why do you require the return value of `scanf()` to be `1`?

Comment: Please explain what you expected to see and what you're seeing...

Comment: You are right Yu.       EOF : I require this because when i want a number as an input (for example when user choses NumberSystem) i want to receive a number not a letter.

Comment: Arkadiy - i wanted to code my program so it would treat characters from CharArray[] As number , for example A - 10 B -11. So the game  would be working on number systems bigger than decimal.

Comment: Look into using `memset` to initialise the `array2` variable.  Don't use `%d` as the `scanf` format parameter, as this will convert the input to an integer and you want it to be a character (it may corrupt your stack).  You don't appear to be using `CharArray`.  Have a look at the `strchr` function for converting your input into a number based on the index of the character in the `CharArray` string.

Comment: the code block begining with: for(i=0; i<NumberSystem*sizeof(int),i++;) the array2[] is allocated as (max) 35*4 bytes which is large enough for 35 ints however the indicated code block is trying to set 35*4 ints. (140*4 bytes)  This overruns the available allocation.

Comment: @JanKowal, I did not ask "what you wanted to write". I asked, in particular, what was the behavior of the program you were expected, and, most importantly, what was actually happening. To answer that question, you need to go in with a debugger or put a lot of printf statements. Here is a valid example: "I expected sscanf to put 'c' in my char variable, instead I see this value which is garbage I don't understand". Once you get to this kind of question, you may be able to just answer it yourself.

Comment: this line: while( array2[number] < MaxRepetitions) 'number' is being used before being set to any specific value.

Comment: `scanf("%s",&Player1);` ==> `scanf("%s", Player1);`, `Player1` is already an array.

Comment: You are all right. I should have deleted smaller problems before looking for some help in a big problem. But anyway, does anybody have any advice how should i try to expand number systems to bigger than decimal?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand what you want to do, you are not far from the solution. But I would recommend to use `%1s` instead of `%c` to read your characters. `%c` accept any characters including blank and newline. In the opposite, `%1s` will skip all eventual blanks and newline.

Simply, as `%1s` gives a null terminated string, you have to use an array (`char anumber[2]`;`), read one character into the array (the second will be`\0`) and affect it to the char you use. For example, you have just to replace

```
scanf("%c", &fnumber);
```

with

```
scanf("%1s", anumber);
fnumber = anumber[0];
```